# Detecting Browser Back Button on SSR React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, server-side-rendering

We have a React app with server-side rendering (Node.js) without React router. We need to send data to the dataLayer (GTM) when the user clicks the browser’s back button. We have tried two methods:

- Listening to the “popstate” event: The event is fired, but the previous page is rendered before the data is pushed to the dataLayer object.
- Listening to the “beforeUnload” event: This event also fires for “refresh” and the “next browser button”. We attempted to detect the navigation type using `window.performance.getEntriesByType`, and we retrieved the previous navigation instead of the current one.

We attempted to place the script in various locations within the app, including attaching it to the head section, but nothing seems to work.